# there are some latency such as keyboard to application or application to monitor. How can I correct this errors and lags?

Tags: c#

I want to produce application that can be measure "reaction time". but there are   some latency  such as keyboard to application or application to monitor. How can I correct this errors and lags?

Comment: I think if i can measure this latency, i can correct it but i don't know how can i measure it.

Comment: [Here](https://danluu.com/keyboard-latency/) is an insightful article an keyboard latency (between 15ms and 50ms). The latency from application to monitor should be determined by the frames-per-second (FPS) setting of the graphics board. FPS 60 means [latency 17ms](https://blog.parsecgaming.com/whats-actually-causing-my-brain-to-detect-lag-in-games-73dbf4430834); FPS 100 would be 10ms.